# How to associate intermediary model's extra column with value from a form

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, web

I have a many to many relationship between Plays and Users with the intermediary WorksOn.

```
class Play < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :works_on
  has_many :users, :through => :works_on
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :works_on
  has_many :plays, :through => :works_on
end

#The WorksOn model also has a :student_role field
class WorksOn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id' #these columns were added via a migration
  belongs_to :play, :foreign_key => 'play_id'
end
```

And in Play's form I have a checkbox to select users

```
<div class="field" id="checkbox-list">
    <%= f.label "Cast and Crew"%> <br />
    <%= collection_check_boxes(:user_id, :user_ids, @users, :id, :simple_to_s) %> #simple_to_s defined in Play's model. @users defined in play controller's 'show' form
</div>
```

In Play's controller I manually create the associations using the checkbox id's.

```
#...

def update
  #grab user_id from params and then the user_ids values
  works_on = params[:user_id]
  works_on = works_on[:user_ids].select{|id|id.length!=0} #rails includes hidden empty string field for checkboxes, must filter it out by removing the 0 length string
  WorksOn.where(:play_id=>@play.id).destroy_all #remove previous associations
  works_on.each do |user_id|
      WorksOn.create(:play_id=>@play.id, :student_role => "aaaaaaaaa",:user_id=>user_id) #create new associations to user   
  end

 #other update stuff  -> respond_to do |format| ...
end
#...
```

The controller currently works but I want to have a text field associated with each check box, and when the admin hits submit the :student_role field uses that value instead of "aaaaaaaaa". Any ideas on how to get this started?

Also, bonus question. Why is :user_id a part of params and not play_params?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being more simple than I expected!

Play's new form

```
<div class="col-md-6 field checkbox-list">
  <%= f.label "Cast and Crew"%> <br />
  <%= collection_check_boxes(:user_id, :user_ids, @users, :id, :simple_to_s) %>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 field user-roles-text-list">
  <%= f.label "Roles and Responsibilities (eg Actor: Hamlet)"%> <br />

  <% @users.each do |user| %> #add a text field for each checkbox
    <%= text_field_tag "user_role[#{user.id}]", nil, placeholder: user.simple_to_s %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Play controller

```
def associate_play_with_users( params )
    user_ids  = params[:user_id] #grab user_id hash from params
    user_roles = params[:user_role]
    user_ids = user_ids[:user_ids] #select the :user_ids key's values from the hash
    user_ids = user_ids.select{|id|id.length!=0}#rails includes hidden empty string field for checkboxes, must filter it out by removing the 0 length string

  WorksOn.where(:play_id=>@play.id).destroy_all #remove previous associations
    user_ids.each do |user_id|
        WorksOn.create(:play_id=>@play.id, :student_role => user_roles[user_id],:user_id=>user_id) #create new associations to user   
  end        
end
```

Parameters

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+7rIGuD59ld5lQHfTtRY130TkGCNnnHm4GJfBQJkP3C0IKmz4YStDxOcuxc2pKsS8nodB/UV1fR5XwWNXXbJ4w==", 
  "play"=>{"title"=>"As You Like It", "description"=>"a dope play faaao sho", "date_of_play(1i)"=>"3000", "date_of_play(2i)"=>"2", "date_of_play(3i)"=>"2", "date_of_play(4i)"=>"00", "date_of_play(5i)"=>"00"}, 
  "user_id"=>{"user_ids"=>["69", "70", ""]}, 
  "user_role"=>{"69"=>"ss", "70"=>"sssasasasas", "71"=>"", "72"=>"", "73"=>"", "74"=>""}, #only the ids from user_id are used, 69 and 70
  "commit"=>"Update Play", "id"=>"17"}
```